# servlet read pdf with rectangle

Tags: java, servlets, itext

`enter code here`
First I make my pdfFile this way:

```
PdfReader pdfr=new PdfReader(filepath1);//existing file
PdfStamper pdfs=new PdfStamper(pdfr, filepath2);//file to be modified
...
PdfContentByte cb=pdfs.getOverContent(1);
cb.setColorFill(new BaseColor(0x00,0x4E,0x44));
cb.rectangle(coordX,min_Y,60,haut);
cb.saveState();
PdfGState state=new PdfGState();
state.setFillOpacity(0.1f);
cb.setGState(state);
cb.fillStroke();
cb.restoreState();
```

The file pdf is correct with Adobe Reader XI,
But when I try to read it with servlet,I can't see any rectangle.
Servlet:

```
protected void doPost(...){
File pdfFile=new File(filepath2);
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(filepath2);
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition","inline;filename=pdfFN);
response.setContentLength((int) filepath2.length());
OutputStream resOS=response.getOutputStream();
int length=1;
byte[] buffer=new byte[8192];
while((length=fis.read(buffer))!=-1)
{resOS.write(buffer,0,length);
}
fis.close();
resOS.flush();resOS.close();
```

What happens?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Servlets don't "read" PDFs and certainly don't "view" PDFs, so I'm sure that you are trying to ask something else, but just like the person who down-voted your question, I have no idea what you're asking. Can you clarify your question. For instance: why are you creating a file on disk? Why aren't you creating the file in memory (which is the most common way to deal with PDFs in the context of servlets). Also: your code snippets contain several errors that make it impossible for them to compile. I corrected some errors, but you should be more accurate when posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize and I'm going to be more clear.

1. First I create a pdf-file (`File1`) which is a weekly grid (with days and hours) with Itext -> OK and no problem to see `File1` with acrobat reader XI.
2. I modify `File1` with `pdfStamper`:

   ```
   PdfReader pdfr=new PdfReader(File1);//existing file code here
   PdfStamper pdfs=new PdfStamper(pdfr, File2);//file to be modified
   ...
   PdfContentByte cb=pdfs.getOverContent(1);
   cb.setColorFill(new BaseColor(0x00,0x4E,0x44));
   cb.rectangle(coordX,min_Y,60,haut);
   Phrase phrase = new Phrase(text, new Font(bf, fontSize));//insert text in rectangle
           ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, phrase,
               // center horizontally
              (float) (coordX + coordX+60) / haut_c,   //haut_c
                   rect1,
               0); 
   cb.saveState();
   PdfGState state=new PdfGState();
   state.setFillOpacity(0.1f);//text is now visible
   cb.setGState(state);
   cb.fillStroke();
   cb.restoreState();
   ```
3. I try to read `File2` in `jsp`:

   ```
   <object data="/Empl_temps/MyServlet?file='+File2+' type="application/pdf" width="600" height="900"></object>
   ```

   MyServlet:

   ```
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       String pdfFileName=request.getParameter("file")+".pdf";
       String contextPath="Y:\\Empl_temps\\";
       System.out.println("Lect_pdf -"+contextPath+pdfFileName);
       File pdfFile=new File(contextPath+pdfFileName);
       FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
       response.setContentType("application/pdf");
       response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename="+pdfFileName);
       response.setContentLength((int)pdfFile.length());
       OutputStream responseOutputStream=response.getOutputStream();
       int length=-1;
       byte[] buffer=new byte[8192];
       while((length=fis.read(buffer))!=-1)
       {
           responseOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
       }
       fis.close();
       responseOutputStream.flush();responseOutputStream.close();
   }
   ```
4. I can read `File2` but I can't see the rectangle,I see only text in rectangle.